# InDesign - how to create an object style that is fixed the same position on each page object style is needed for

Tags: adobe-indesign, smartobject, style

I am a graphic designer who is new to the publishing industry.

Trying to create object styles - how do I get the object I draw to fit to the exact position on the page each time? I've got as far as creating the object style ready for an image to be placed within it but when I click the object style, it moves the frame up but I want it more or less central to the page. Anyone able to provide a step by step process please?

Comment: Are you using a CC version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move the object to the master page, which makes it locked in the same position for every page using that master page.

Later edit: the object style panel does not allow you to set (X,Y) coordinates for an object inside a page. To correctly place an image at the very center of a page:

1. select your object
2. click the center of the 'Reference Point' panel (see below)
3. do the math and fill in the X and Y fields (see below) to 1/2 of your page width and 1/2 of your page height

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your time messaging. For publishing, I must build the file differently. To save time overall, it is more efficient to use the 'object style' tool to determine where the object will be placed within the page. However, I am struggling to set the x and y to a fixed place within the page - think I am missing some steps to ensure it is central to the page?

Comment: Ok. What size is your page?

Comment: Object Styles - as the name suggests - controls the way an object looks, or it is 'styled', not the position of an object. See my update above.

Comment: @Lucian CC2018 introduces the position attribute of an object style. Which is why I asked for Lady T's version. So... I'm asking again ^^

Comment: It does? Interesting, ok..

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I am using CC2019. I've managed to move the object style using the x and y values within the object style settings. Thanks you for feedback Lucian and Vinny.  

Steps I took to get there: 

1. Create new ‘object style’ > create style name

2. ‘Size and Position Options’ > Adjust: Height and Width

3. Position: X and Y > reference top left > X offset = 0mm from page > Y offset = 12p5 from edge

4. Click OK